# Custom code not implementing functionality

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I am writing a trigger on Account when Account Active field is updated from ‘Yes’
to ‘No’ then check all opportunities associated with the account. Update all
Opportunities Stage to close lost if stage not equal to close won.

I have no idea why my code is not working. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after update) {

//AccountTriggerHandler.updateRating(Trigger.new);

if (trigger.isafter && trigger.isupdate)
{
    AccountTriggerHandler.afterUpdate(Trigger.new, trigger.oldmap);
}

}


public class AccountTriggerHandler {



public static void afterUpdate (List<Account> accList, map<id,account> oldAccMap)
{

    map<id,account> updatedAccMap = new map<id,account>();
    list<opportunity> oppList = new list<opportunity>();
    for (account acc: accList)
    {
        if (oldAccMap.get(acc.id).active__c=='Yes' && acc.active__c=='No')
        updatedAccMap.put(acc.id, acc);
    }

    if (updatedAccMap.size()>0)
    {
        for (opportunity opp: [select id, stagename from opportunity where accountid in : updatedAccMap.keyset() ])
        {
            if ( opp.stagename!='Closed Lost' && opp.stagename!='Closed Won')
            {
                    opp.stagename='Closed Lost';
                    oppList.add(opp);

            }
        }
    }

    if (oppList.size()>0)
    {
        update oppList;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you updated an Account  Active field from Yes to No

Comment: Are you getting any error while changing the Field from Yes to No.

Comment: I dont get any error while updating account active from Yes to No, but the corresponding stage change of the opportunity records is not happening.

Comment: I tried the same code in my org and it is working as expected. Did you try to debug the apex class?

Comment: Apologies, my trigger was not active. Thanks for your efforts.